# Best way to handle unused function arguments

Tags: python, function, higher-order-functions

Suppose a user gives me a list with a variable number of functions that have a fixed number of arguments a, b, and c. All with fixed type. Sometimes all the arguments are used, but sometimes not. For example:

```
def two_list_sum_mult(a: List, b: List, c: int):
  """ Sums the elements on each list and multiplies it by a constant.
  """
  return c * (sum(a) + sum(b))

def list_sum_mult(a: List, b: List, c: int):
  """ Sums the elements on list a and multiplies it by a constant.
  """
  return c * sum(a)

def list_sum_reciprocals(a: List, b: List, c: int):
  """ Returns the sum of the reciprocals of each element of the list a.
  """
  return sum([1/x for x in a])
```

The user passes a list of functions, and the arguments to my function. Then, my function loops over all the functions, computes the result, and then computes something with the result. For example:

```
def function_sum(functions: List, a: List, b: List, c: int):
  """ Computes all the functions and adds the results.
  """
  total = 0
  for f in functions:
    total += f(a, b, c)
  
  return total
```

What is the best way to handle the arguments of the functions when they are not used? In other words: is it ok to have unused arguments for functions, or is there a better way to do all of this?

Comment: It's perfectly fine in contexts like this.

Comment: Best in terms of what and according to who?

Comment: Thank you for your response @LordRatte. I actually don't know! What I meant is more along the lines of correctness, and/or pythonic way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is okay to leave unused arguments, however it may be misleading and some linters would complain.

Another way you could make it clearer that the variables are not used is using `_` as the variable name or prepending `_` to the variable name. For example:

```py
def two_list_sum_mult(a: List, b: List, c: int):
  """ Sums the elements on each list and multiplies it by a constant.
  """
  return c * (sum(a) + sum(b))

# replace `b` with `_` or `_b`
def list_sum_mult(a: List, _, c: int):
  """ Sums the elements on list a and multiplies it by a constant.
  """
  return c * sum(a)

# as you only care about the first argument you can ignore the others with `*_`
def list_sum_reciprocals(a: List, *_):
  """ Returns the sum of the reciprocals of each element of the list a.
  """
  return sum([1/x for x in a])
```

Comment: Hi @luigibertaco, thank you for your answer. Yes, something I find a bit confusing is that my editor (VSC) complains about it, so I was unsure of whether I was doing something wrong.

Comment: I added some comments to help you understanding what was changed

Answer (score 1):

Its ok to have unused arguments, you could have those arguments have a default value